# Telling aptitude I've already installed something

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, texlive, auctex, aptitude

Hi, I know this might be a non-sense question, but I have to ask. I installed TeXLive 2009 on Ubuntu 10.04 (x64), but I did it manually with the "*install-tl*" perl script following the directions on http://tug.org/texlive/doc.html. All the other software I've previously installed was through

```
sudo aptitude install package-name
```

The reason why I did a manual installation was because *tlmgr* doesn't install with the aptitude repositories version, and I wanted a quick way to install/uninstall TeXLive-latex related packages. Moreover, I read that, as a general rule, TeXLive Ubuntu repositories' are generally outdated.

The problem I'm facing now is that I need to install other related software, for example, `auctex` and when I issue

```
sudo aptitude install auctex
```

I get that all these packages will be installed:

```
 auctex emacs23{a} emacs23-bin-common{a} emacs23-common{a} 
  emacsen-common{a} lacheck{a} latex-beamer{a} latex-xcolor{a} lmodern{a} 
  luatex{a} pgf{a} preview-latex-style{a} prosper{a} ps2eps{a} 
  tex-common{a} texlive-base{a} texlive-binaries{a} texlive-common{a} 
  texlive-doc-base{a} texlive-extra-utils{a} texlive-font-utils{a} 
  texlive-generic-recommended{a} texlive-latex-base{a} 
  texlive-latex-base-doc{a} texlive-latex-recommended{a} 
  texlive-latex-recommended-doc{a} texlive-luatex{a} texlive-pstricks{a} 
  texlive-pstricks-doc{a}
```

Even if I try something like

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends auctex
```

I still get

```
 auctex emacs23{a} emacs23-bin-common{a} emacs23-common{a} 
  emacsen-common{a} preview-latex-style{a} tex-common{a}
```

Which is *way* better than before, but I'm still getting `tex-common` that is normally installed when TeXLive full installation is performed (I think). `tex-common` in turn, is installed because of `preview-latex-style`, which in turn is needed because `auctex` requires so.

So, my question. Is there any way to tell aptitude "*Hey I've already installed these so don't worry about dependencies, I have these under control despite you'd never seen them before?*"? Will `auctex` even work despite the manual installation of TeXLive?

Any help or idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install a program that doesn't come through the packaging system, install it under `/usr/local` (or under `/opt`, or in your home directory, just not in `/usr`). Unless you're short of disk space, you can leave the packaged version if there is one.

Occasionally it can be useful to pretend a package is installed. This can be done by installing a dummy package that does nothing but require and provide dependencies. Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu) provide the `equivs-build` command in the `equivs` package. Quoting from the package description:

> This package provides a tool to create Debian packages that only contain dependency information.
>
> One use for this is to create a metapackage: a package whose sole purpose is to declare dependencies and conflicts on other packages so that these will be automatically installed, upgraded, or removed.
>
> Another use is to circumvent dependency checking.  If a package P is not installed on the system, packages that depend on P cannot normally be installed.  However, if functionality equivalent to P is known to be installed, this tool can be used to trick the Debian package management system into believing that package P is actually installed. NOTE: this should be considered a crude hack to work around awkward situations, not a normal solution.

Comment: Interesting, I did't know about equivs. It is definitely a plausible solution at least for the auctex problem... On the other hand, TexLive 2009 installs by default on /urs/local/texlive/2009/, so I could have left it there along with the Ubuntu's repo in a different directory, but then again I'm running low on resources at least on this laptop. I'll give it a try on my desktop PC. Thanks!

Comment: Gilles, I'm working now with the Editor Kile which despite it installs some KDE libraries, it allows to indicate where the LaTeX/TeX software is located (au contraire to auctex which requires to provide this information during build via ./configure). I also believe TeXLive 2010 is going to be out soon, so I'll keep this place posted when I try on my desktop PC to see if it works. I realize now that, even though, it may present a problem to mess up aptitude, in the long run, Ubuntu's repo requires to MANUALLY update each CTAN package, so updating presents the same hassle, one way or the other.

Comment: @l30nc1t0: AucTeX can be told where the TeX installation is at any time. Set the `TeX-macro-global` variable to the list of directories containing TeX style files, and run `TeX-auto-generate-global` once. See “Customizing” in the manual.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now that you mention it, at gnu.org online documentation, but the problem here's I'm definitely not competent enough on Emacs (or Lisp-related files?). I read the section on installing and configuring auctex. You brought up my attention to customizing, and I'm peering it now, but I cannot even grasp what are they talking about. I was mislead by Wikipedia and the summary of features of auctex. I thought XEmacs was like GEdit or something. I apologize for being a nOOb in these matters: I suffer from 'lack-of-Windows-like' syndrome, XD.

Answer (score 1):

I can't take the whole mess of `aptitude` doing bananas just for the sake of having the most up to date LaTeX distribution. I tried **DaveParillo**'s advice, installed with

```
aptitude install --without-recommends --prompt --safe-resolver auctex
```

It installed `auctex` and `emacs`. It didn't work. Apparently, `auctex` configuration has to be done from source, so the only solution to my above question would be to *forget* about `aptitude` (so yet again, **DaveParillo** was right, I messed up `aptitude`) and build `auctex` from source. And as you may be already figuring it out, this a huge ball coming, since every time I might need something related with LaTeX I'll need to build from source each and every program, so... Answering my second question: no, it will not work unless `auctex` is built from source with `./configure --funky-options-about-where-your-tex-installation-may-reside`. Moreover, `auctex` extension was *gone* from Emacs when I restarted.

I removed `auctex` with

```
sudo aptitude purge auctex
```

and I removed TeXLive 2009 with "*tlmgr*", I'll install the one from Ubuntu's repositories. And I'll cope with that in the meantime. I love `aptitude` way of handling installations, but sometimes is just... Argh. Answering the main question "Is there any way to tell `aptitude` you've already done something manually?": no, in this particular experiment of mine, but I don't know if this might be possible with some *experienced* workaround solution.

Sorry for the inconvenience, guys. If this were a testing environment I'd go ahead and try doing everything manually, even if that means reinstalling the OS many times. But I just needed this working, and I can't go with that option. Thanks to everyone for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You have bypassed the normal aptitude dependency system, so I think you may have problems.  The simplest, but possibly tedious answer is to run aptitude with the `--prompt` option - it will ask you before each install (or removal) and you can choose which packages to install.

Since this question deals with hacking latex, you may to post this on the [Tex - LaTex stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your time Dave, I tried it, too bad it didn't work: you were right about messing up the dependencies with aptitude.

Comment: --prompt or -P didn't work?

Comment: Dave, yes. I didn't try it only with --prompt but with --without-recommends and --safe-resolver. The first one, following your advise so it would ask me about which package I would like to install. The second one needed because if not it would go with those 20 or so extra packages. And just in case, I went ahead and added the resolver, to avoid any issues. It went ahead and installed everything, prompting only for "Install [y/n]?" once.